# Is there a way to fetch an @Embedded field lazily?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, jpa-2.1

I'm having some trouble trying to figure out how to set up a class that has an `@Embedded` field that must be fetched lazily. I tried to annotate the field with `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`, but it causes the persistence API to treat the field as a basic type that implements `Serializable`, so it maps the field to a `BYTEA` field in the database (postgresql). I tested it on Derby too, and the same happens.

I also tried to annotate the fields of the `@Embeddable` class individually with `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` instead of annotating the `@Embedded` field of the entity that has it. The generated schema is correct in this case, but the fields are fetched eagerly when I load instances of the entity.

My understanding is that the `@Basic` annotation is used on basic fields/properties only, so the first case is expected. But why the fields of the `@Embeddable` class are fetched eagerly even if they are annotated with `@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`? Also, I know that the fetch strategy can be specified by the `@Basic` and relationship annotations, but is there any other way to specify that fields should be fetched lazily? I'm using EclipseLink 2.6, but let me know if the behaviour is different for other versions of EclipseLink or for another provider.

Answer (score 1):

Directly you cant, because of how @Embedded objects work, but by setting attributes in the object it should work.

@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)

Remember that lazy should be use only on collections or big objects, and that setting fetch type on lazy is only a clue for provider, it doesn't mean that it will always fetch it lazy rather than eager.